# Apache RewriteRule giving permission error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but one of my 2 RewriteRule are working, while the other is not.

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?api$ tmp/api.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?funsite$ tmp/funsite.php [L]
```

And here is what's in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/apache">
    Options -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The `RewriteRule` directing to `tmp/api.php` is the only one not working.

The Error on a browser are: **You don't have permission to access /api/ on this server.**

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the rewrite rule, its misconfiguration of folder accesses and apache's user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule won't rewrite `/api/`, because of the `$`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?api$ tmp/api.php [L]
```

It won't match if there's anything after `i`. To fix it, change it to

```
RewriteRule ^/?api/?$ tmp/api.php [L]
```

Note the additional `/?` before the `$`. You probably want to make similar changes to all other rules that attempt to match pseudo-directories like this.